# Matlab: Calling user defined function

Tags: function, matlab

I am creating a user defined function in this manner

```
   function y=add(a)

   y=a*a;
```

Now, this function is in a separate .m file.

I want to make use of this function but I am not getting it how to call it

Do I need another .m file to call it? and #include the above .m file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First**, you need to name the file `add.m` (i.e. exactly the **same** name your function has) and you can place it anywhere in the current matlab path (your current working directory is fine).

**Second**, you should call your function doing (e.g.) `y=add(5)` either from command line or from another matlab script/function.

In those scripts there's no need for further `#include`-like stuff, provided, again, `add.m` is in your working path.